# linking selenium with python not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

im trying to get selenium to work within python but when i try to import it it does not show as available. "module not found". I have selenium as a site-package in my python files onm my computer. Can someone help me understand how to link selenium to python.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

```sh
$ pip3 install -U selenium
$ python3
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

if you use virtual environment (always a good idea):

```sh
$ python3 -m venv /path/to/venv
$ . /path/to/venv/bin/activate
$ (venv) pip install -U selenium
$ (venv) python
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```